# EmberJS Mirage 404 error on get /rentals

Tags: ember.js, http-status-code-404, ember-cli-mirage

I'm following tutorial on this page (https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/tutorial/installing-addons/) until the next tutorial page. (Actually I follow until finished the tutorial.)

Everything seems to working fine. ✔
Ember server is serving and display in the browser correctly. ✔
Ember development build also display correctly. ✔

But Ember production build give me **/rentals 404 error**. ✖
How to fix this 404 error on **production build**?

Here is my **mirage/config.js**

```
export default function() {

  // These comments are here to help you get started. Feel free to delete them.

  /*
    Config (with defaults).

    Note: these only affect routes defined *after* them!
  */

  // this.urlPrefix = '';    // make this `http://localhost:8080`, for example, if your API is on a different server
  // this.namespace = '';    // make this `api`, for example, if your API is namespaced
  // this.timing = 400;      // delay for each request, automatically set to 0 during testing

  /*
    Shorthand cheatsheet:

    this.get('/posts');
    this.post('/posts');
    this.get('/posts/:id');
    this.put('/posts/:id'); // or this.patch
    this.del('/posts/:id');

    http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.2.x/shorthands/
  */

  this.get('/rentals', function(db, request) {
    let rentals = [{
        type: 'rentals',
        id: 1,
        attributes: {
          title: 'Grand Old Mansion',
          owner: 'Veruca Salt',
          city: 'San Francisco',
          type: 'Estate',
          bedrooms: 15,
          image: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cb/Crane_estate_(5).jpg'
        }
      }, {
        type: 'rentals',
        id: 2,
        attributes: {
          title: 'Urban Living',
          owner: 'Mike Teavee',
          city: 'Seattle',
          type: 'Condo',
          bedrooms: 1,
          image: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Alfonso_13_Highrise_Tegucigalpa.jpg'
        }
      }, {
        type: 'rentals',
        id: 3,
        attributes: {
          title: 'Downtown Charm',
          owner: 'Violet Beauregarde',
          city: 'Portland',
          type: 'Apartment',
          bedrooms: 3,
          image: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Wheeldon_Apartment_Building_-_Portland_Oregon.jpg'
        }
      }];

    if(request.queryParams.city !== undefined) {
      let filteredRentals = rentals.filter(function(i) {
        return i.attributes.city.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.queryParams.city.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
      });
      return { data: filteredRentals };
    } else {
      return { data: rentals };
    }
  });

}
```

The url prefix and namespace don't change anything, still /rentals 404 error.

> GET http://localhost/rentals 404 Not Found
>   "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/rentals"
>   Error while processing route: index Ember Data Request GET /rentals returned a 404

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ember-cli-mirage is disabled in production build, you should explicitly enable it in config:

```
if (environment === 'production') {
  ENV['ember-cli-mirage'] = {
    enabled: true
  };
}
```

[Mirage Documentation](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.2.x/configuration/#enabled)

Answer (score 0):

The docs have been updated to include a fix for this issue.

Now if you go to the section in the docs called [Setting up Application Tests to use Mirage](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/ember-data/#toc_setting-up-application-tests-to-use-mirage) you will see it says to open `/tests/acceptance/list-rentals-test.js` and insert in this import statements at the top:

```
import setupMirage from 'ember-cli-mirage/test-support/setup-mirage';
```

Then in `tests/acceptance/list-rentals-test.js` and add a `setupMirage(hooks);` right after `setupApplicationTest(hooks)`

```
module('Acceptance | list rentals', function(hooks) {
  setupApplicationTest(hooks);
  setupMirage(hooks);
  ...
}
```

Then the data and the tests will pass.

Comment: Why did I get `-1` for this?